# Getting an exception "positioned update not supported" while reading data from getCursorName function

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I am working on a project in itext and when I am trying to get the data from database and fill it into a already present pdf using itext I get this error "positioned update not supported.

```
package itext.sample;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

/**
 * @author prithvi
 *
 */
public class FirstPdf {

    private static final String Result = "D:/Eclipse Java/image.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,IOException,DocumentException {
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }
      System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://69.167.139.172/bluedb",
                            "color", "prithvi");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    try {
            Statement stm = null;
            stm = connection.createStatement();//creating database query
            ResultSet rs = null;
            rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Sec1");
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("D:/Eclipse Java/HiltonForms2014_r.pdf");
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(Result));
            AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
            form.setField("LASTNAME", rs.getCursorName());
            stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
            stamper.close();
            reader.close();

            connection.close();

    }

                 catch (DocumentException | SQLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: I've updated your question because (1.) your allegation that you need `PdfWriter` doesn't make sense, (2.) code that is commented away is irrelevant, and (3.) this is an SQL question. Your problem has nothing to do with iText or PDF! It's a pure JDBC question.

Answer (score 1):

Your database doesn't support the `getCursorName()` hence a database access error is thrown.

Looking at your code, it is hard to understand why you'd need that method. You are getting all the fields of a table named `Sec1` and you want to get a `String` with a name.

Suppose that the field with that name is named `lastname`, theb you can get the value of that field like this:

```
String lastname = null;
if (rs != null)
    lastname = rs.getString("lastname");
```

You can now use `lastname` to fill out the field:

```
form.setField("LASTNAME", lastname);
```

Obviously only you know if `"lastname"` is what the field is called in your database. This example won't work if the field is named `"last_name"`, `"lname"` or any other name.

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed database question I should have realized it my bad. sorry